# Сохранение файла в корень

Tags: c++, dll

Пишу экстеншен для одной игры. Обычная ддл-ка в виде логера. Имеется вот такой кусок кода:

```
int __stdcall RVExtensionArgs(char *output, int outputSize, const char *function, const char **args, int argsCnt)
{
  if (!strncmp(function, "logger", 2))
  {
    std::string fnc = args[0];
    std::string ln = args[1];
    std::string dir = args[2];
    //Output it as the .dll result to arma 3
  strncpy_s(output, outputSize, "Log created!", _TRUNCATE);

  //Get current Server Time for loggin
  time_t currentTime;
  struct tm *localTime;

  time(&currentTime);                   // Get the current time
  localTime = localtime(&currentTime);  // Convert the current time to the local time

  //Convert them to strings
  string Day = to_string(localTime->tm_mday);
  string Month = to_string(localTime->tm_mon + 1);
  string Year = to_string(localTime->tm_year + 1900);
  string Hour = to_string(localTime->tm_hour);
  string Min = to_string(localTime->tm_min);
  string Sec = to_string(localTime->tm_sec);

  //Create Dir for Logging
  // std::string dir = "D:\\A3Logs";
  // CreateDirectoryA(dir, NULL);

  //define the path and filename and log it.
  string logname = dir + "/" + ln + ".txt";
  logname.erase(remove( logname.begin(), logname.end(), '\"' ),logname.end());

  std::ofstream log(logname, std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out);
  log << Day << "-" << Month << "-" << Year << " - " << Hour << ":" << Min << ":" << Sec << " :: " << fnc << "\n";

}
  return 0;
};
```

. Который по сути и представляет собой логгер. В переменную dir должен приходить абсолютный путь для сохранения файла. Но хотелось бы если приходит в аргумент пустой стринг, то файл должен сохраняться в корне с длл-кой. Что-то на подобии шарпового Environment.CurrentDirectory. Алсо, экстеншен будет компилиться под линукс.

Comment: [не по теме] Почитайте про [std::strftime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime)

Comment: Обычно такие параметры в конфигурационный файл заносят :) Сегодня Вы хотите положить его рядом с dll-кой, а завтра - уже в другом месте. Дело, конечно, Ваше, но Вы все же подумайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux-based ОС: [**спасибо за замечание @Fat-Zer**]

```
#include <unistd.h>

char buf[PATH_MAX];
readlink("/proc/self/exe", buf, PATH_MAX);
```

Windows: [GetModuleFilename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx)

MacOS:

```
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>

char path[1024];
uint32_t size = sizeof(path);
if (_NSGetExecutablePath(path, &size) == 0)
    printf("executable path is %s\n", path);
```

Comment: текущий каталог — это совсем не то же самое, что и директория с библиотекой...

Comment: Т.е., неправильно использовать вышеприведенный код на стороне библиотеки, ожидая, что результатом окажется путь к директории, где лежит библиотека?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, все, понял Вас. Спасибо за замечание, сейчас поправлю!

Comment: для linux и mac указанные методы позволяют найти только путь к исполняемому файлу, а не к библиотеке... хотя для этих систем выбранное решение является абсолютным моветоном к основной задаче... да и для win в современном мире, пожалуй, тоже...

Comment: @isnullxbh
 А можно по подробней с GetModuleFilename? Как правильно написать проверку на пустой стринг?

Comment: @isnullxbh Что-то на подобии такого? if(dir = ""){
 GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
}

Comment: @HoneyCake, похоже на правду )